# How to make new column values based on part of string from another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is the final line of code that creates the stock options dataframe screenshot below. It's not ideal, but because of the nature of the code and the api it uses, I think this is the easiest way to supplement my question.

What I want to do is create a new column that is just the ticker symbol. For example all of the stock options for Tesla would have a separate column that is just "TSLA". And all of the Apple stock options would have a separate column that is just "AAPL". So most rows would have the same value. I would imagine there is a way to take the first word from the "SYMBOL" column before the "_" or the first word from the "DESCRIPTION" column before the space and put that value in a new column.

```
call.option.dataframe = do.call(rbind, options.chain.datalist)
```

[image: dataframe screenshot]

> Blockquote

Comment: You could use something like `df$NEW_SYMBOL <- gsub("(\\w+)_\\w+", "\\1", df$SYMBOL)`.

Comment: This works except for the rows in which the strike price has a .5 in it. For example in row 68, the symbol and description column has 692.5. The NEW_SYMBOL column will return TSLA.5 instead of TSLA.

Comment: Well... try `gsub("([A-z]+)_.*", "\\1", df$SYMBOL)`

Answer (score 4):

We could use `separate` from `tidyr` package.
Below code creates in dataframe `df` additional two columns out of column `SYMBOL` -> `A` and `B` separated by `_`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    separate(SYMBOL,c("A", "B"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
```